# center a div box in the middle of the page using css

Tags: css

I want to center a div right in the middle of the page, I tried `top:30%`, but when the window is resized off the alignment.

```
<div id=cent></div>
```

Thanks
Jean

Comment: This type of question needs some sample code if some tries to answer it... Without any idea about how the div is positioned within it's parent elements and siblings, there is no way to understand your problem.. cheers..!

Comment: Its just a simple div no parent or child

Answer (score 18):

If you know the height/width of that div (for instance, it will be 100px X 200px) then you can do it like this:

```
#cent {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin-top:-50px; /* this is half the height of your div*/  
  margin-left:-100px; /*this is half of width of your div*/
}
```

UPDATE: another option: see http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center (Centering vertically)

Comment: Irrespective of the size of the div, it needs to be aligned

Comment: And (http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp) here they say that Good Ol' IE do not support most the atributes like table-cell etc...

Comment: Yes, W3Schools say it, but I am watching this page: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center-example.html with IE8 and it works perfectly ;-) According to QuirksMode.org, which I trust more than W3Schools, you have to force "IE8 as IE8" mode to make it work: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Comment: IE8 is not "Good Ol' IE".. IE >= 7 already supports a lot, but IE6 is still a problem for a lot of people.

Comment: Note that you can't use 100% height on table-cell. Please see more details on my answer.

Comment: This answer is outdated, definitely use flex. See @alephao's answer below.

Answer (score 9):

I know this question is pretty old, but I stumbled upon it, and I'll probably look for it again in the future.

In my case, the content has a variable height, and I don't want to use absolute positioning, so I used a flexbox container instead. You just need to wrap your content inside a div with the following style:

```
.container {
  min-height: 100vh; /* minimum height = screen height */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Example: https://codepen.io/alephao/pen/mdPRYqZ

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is 9 years old, but having stumbled upon it 9 years later, maybe someone else could do the same.

**This is my working solution:**

```
#cent {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

By doing this  it will set the `width` and `height` to 500px, then it will set the `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom` constraints to 0, and finally, by setting the margins to `auto`, the box will be put in the exact middle of the window. This will also be responsive.

Answer (score 1):

Adding notes to naivists' link (to w3c tips site):
`display:table-cell` does not work with `height:100%`. So, if you want to vertically center an element, which you don't know its height, on a page, you need to put it inside a container with `display:table` and `height:100%`, and another container with `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align:middle`.

Furthermore, if you want to center it horizontally, you need to specify `width:100%` to body, the outer container, and give `text-align:center` to inner container. The content should have `display:inline-block`, and to reset alignment, `text-align:left`.

Ultimately, it becomes as follows:

```
<style>
#vcontainer {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#hcontainer {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
#content {
  display: inline-block;
  border: lightGray 1px solid;
  background-color: lightBlue;
  text-align: left;
}
</style>
<body>
  <div id="vcontainer"><div id="hcontainer">
    <div id="content">
      Hoyjo!<br>
      I have returned to my hometown!<br>
      Lolololo lololo lololo lololo lololo!<br>
    </div>
  </div></div>
</body>
```

I cannot guarantee it will work on legacy browsers (IE6/7). It will work on IE8 provided it runs on IE8 standards (yes, this will screw your mind. Thanks, MS!), and you must give `<html>` and `<body>` the `height:100%`.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#box{
background-color: green;
width:100px;
height:100px;
margin:auto; /*This will center it horizontally but not vertically*/
}
```

Watch out of the quotes or double quotes around the id "box", you need them.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div id="content"
                 style="text-align: center;
                 vertical-align: middle;
                 border-color: #000000;
                 border-width: 1px;
                 border-style: solid;
                 margin-top: 25%;
                 margin-bottom: 25%;">
                hi
            </div>
```

This worked for me...

Edit : This will align the whole div... regardless of the size of the div or the page... Assuming that this id the only div in the whole page...

Comment: I just need to align the div not the text

Answer (score 0):

If you want the top middle:
HTML:

```
<div class="cent">
  <!-- code -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cent {
  align: center;
}
```

and if you want direct middle, use the same HTML but change the CSS to:

```
.cent {
  align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 45%;
}
```

Example Code: [jsfiddle.net/Lzdvnk29](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzdvnk29) (it may not look centered if you
look at it, but if it is a full HTML page it will show in the direct middle)

Answer (score 0):

I tried @alephao's answer and wasn't enough cause the div stood at the top.
So I made this one which works for me:

```css
#cent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 25vh;
}
```

Hope this is what you search for.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me:

```
#cent {
        height: 600px;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: inherit;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's how:

```
#cent
{
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-right:50px;
}
```

Now your div is going to be 50px from left and right and centered in whatever container you have it in.

Answer (score -1):

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
margin: auto;
```