# How to center div the whole screen page using css

Tags: html, css

I have got below div in my html and it has a label in it.

```
<div id="divInvalid" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="lblInvalidUser" class="error" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

Now I want to put css on the DIV or Label show it will appear to middle of page.

Please suggest!!

Comment: Is the div the size of the whole screen or just centred?

Comment: DIV will be center to Whole screen

Comment: possible duplicate of [center a div box in the middle of the page using css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498003/center-a-div-box-in-the-middle-of-the-page-using-css)

Comment: What if we do using jquery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210717/using-jquery-to-center-a-div-on-the-screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try :

```
<div id="divInvalid" runat="server" style="text-align:center;">
        <asp:Label ID="lblInvalidUser" class="error" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

Comment: width should be 100% `style="text-align:center;width:100%"`

Comment: @mgraph div is 100% width by **default** !

Comment: But I want my label to the center of the page, above code only puts its center but at the top of page only

Comment: @m.s. you should **write** these things ! we are not supposed to guess that !  for your question - you will need **JavavScript** or you should use a `table` with `td` which has **Vertical-align:middle**

Comment: sorry any examples, as this message comes first on the page get loaded and this showing and hiding the above label is done through c# code behind. Please suggest!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#divInvalid{margin:0 auto;width:1024px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `display:inline-block` to `label`

```
#divInvalid{
 text-align:center
}

label{display:inline-block;text-align:left;}
```

Comment: @RoyiNamir; check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279294/how-do-i-center-an-inline-block-floated-header-with-no-extra-markup/7279451#7279451

Comment: I dont know what youre talking about but to center a span in div you dont have to make it display inline-block... inline is enough.http://jsfiddle.net/vpcXS/3/

Comment: may be you have to check this link to understand why i use inline-block instead of inline http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block

Answer (score 0):

Give the div an exact size 950, 1000, 1050... and then put in the CSS :

```
margin:0 auto; width: ...;
```

This should fix the problem.

Comment: #[name]{ margin:0 auto; width: ...;}
(...): what ever size of div.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#divInvalid{
  margin:0 auto;
  width:1024px;
}

#divInvalid label{
  height:80px; width:200px;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin:-40px 0 0 -100px;
}
```